# strcat implementation using pointers

Tags: c++, c, initialization, malloc

Could anyone know that when I write in this way, the program crashes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void mystrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    while(*s++);
    s--;
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}

int main(void) {
    int size = 1024;
    char *s1, *s2;

    s1 = (char *)malloc(size);
    //s1[0] = '\0';   ********NOTE THIS********
    s2 = (char *)malloc(size);
    //s2[0] = '\0';   ********NOTE THIS********
    mystrcat( s1, "Hello " );
    mystrcat( s2, "World" );
    mystrcat( s1, s2 );
    printf( "\"%s\"\n", s1 );
    return 0;
}
```

But strangely, when I do not use those two "//" comments, it works!!! 
So why adding those simple `s2[0] = '\0';` could make this program work.

Comment: C or C++? choose one,

Comment: Avoid loops like `while(*s++);` with a semicolon on the same line. That's very bad practice since the reader can't tell if the semicolon is accidental or intentional. A better alternative is`while(*s++)` new line `{}`.

Comment: Also, algorithm-wise it would be better to do `while(*s != '\0') { s++; }` because that stops at the null terminator and doesn't iterate 1 step too far.

Comment: or even `while (*s++) continue;`.  It's easy to hit accidentally the `;`, but not the complete word `continue`.

Comment: even `while (*++s) continue;` stops at the null char and doesn't need the `s--;` behind.

Answer (score 4):

When you allocate memory, either through the old C `malloc` function or the C++ `new` operator, that memory is not initialized in any way. Reading that memory as it were initialized leads to *undefined behavior*, and undefined behavior (or UB as it's often shortened) is one of the main reasons for crashes.

Comment: I've always disliked how people tend to insinuate that *undefined behaviour* is *unknowable behaviour*. "Undefined behaviour" is not actually undefined, it just means the behaviour is defined outside the C++ Standard and is possibly context dependant.

Comment: @Born2Smile If something is defined in the standard, it's defined behavior. The standard also says that some things are *implementation defined*, which means the compiler and/or standard library implementation can implement something any way they see fit. Then there's *undefined* behavior, and that's anything that's not in the standard *as well* as things explicitly marked out as undefined *in the specification*. Reading uninitialized memory is *not* implementation defined, it's undefined, it's contents is *indeterminate*, and it's definitely not defined outside the specification.

Comment: I agree with your comment  100% until "it's definitely not defined outside the specification.".  A given OS/compiler may defined accessing uninitialized memory to return 0 or fault.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I got it. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the contents of memory is not *indeterminate*, all you need to do to determine it is read it. "Reading uninitialized memory" is very well defined. It returns the value that the memory location has. You may not know in advance what the value is or which process set that value, but the value is there none the less set by some process since power up. Thus the reading of uninitialized memory is implementation defined, only it might not be explicitly defined, and the value may be very dependent on timing due to the scheduling of processes.You may consider it indeterministic perhaps

Comment: @Born2Smile The very premises of deterministic behavior is that the behavior can be predicted beforehand. If you can't tell what the contents of some memory is, its contents is indeterminate. And trying to use uninitialized memory as it was properly initialized (like expecting an array of integers to contain specific values) can't be done. Or worse, lets say you have an array of pointers, and the array is uninitialized, what do you think happen when you try to dereference one of the pointers? It might *seem* to work, in reality your program is *ill-formed* and won't work as expected.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree that using uninitialized memory is unwise, no argument there. Trying to use an uninitialized array might not be very useful, but it is not at all impossible. If you ask the computer to read from the array it will do as it is told. The trouble with dereferencing uninitialized pointers is not that they are uninitialized, but that you don't know where they are pointing, and thus if you haven't set them or at least checked that they point somewhere, you don't know if the address within corresponds to a memory location, you have read/write access to.

Answer (score 3):

The returned pointer by `malloc()` is not guaranteed to be `0`-filled, (*or, initialized to any value, at all, for that matter*). So other than the `s1[0] = '\0';` part, `while(*s++);` may not be doing what you're expecting.

Without the initial zeroing part, `while(*s++);` cannot prevent the read-before-write scenario.

It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of

1. Reading unitialized memory location (indeterminate value)
2. Going past the allocated memory, in search of terminating null.

In this case, as pointed out by Mr. Peter in the comments,  however, the first point itself causes the UB and there is no guarantee that it will *reach* to the second point. However, in some other scenario, even if the memory is initialized but not null-terminated, you'll hit the second point to invoke the UB.

Comment: The act of reading an uninitialised variable (or array element) gives undefined behaviour all on its own.   That occurs first.   There is no guarantee that the loop will then proceed to search for the terminating NULL.

Comment: @Peter You're right. I was just trying to point out the probable causes. I'll add a line to ensure your point gets highlighted. :)

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you. :) I am new to C, so pointer is a little scary for me.

Answer (score 1):

In C every string is terminated by the '\0' character.
`malloc` just allocates the memory, it doesn't writes the '\0' for You.
If You don't add it the program won't know where is the end of the string, and propably will try to read some memory after the actual string, that is not allocated, so it will cause undefined behaviour.

Here actually the `mystrcat` function increments the pointer until it points to a '\0' character or a `0`.
But if there's no 0 found in the allocated memory, then after the next incrementation of the pointer, it will point to some unallocated memory.
Dereferencing it now will cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, you need to initialize that memory. You can do that in more than one way, but one way would be to use calloc instead of malloc. If you change these two lines:

```
s1 = (char *)malloc(size);    
s2 = (char *)malloc(size);
```

to:

```
s1 = calloc(size,sizeof(*s1));   
s2 = calloc(size,sizeof(*s2));
```

Your program will run.

Comment: 1) Why cast the return value of `malloc()/calloc()` 2) Why `sizeof(char)` when 1` would do?  Suggest `s1 = calloc(size, sizeof *s1);`  No unneeded cast, certainty that the right `sizeof(type)` is used.

Comment: @chux Thanks, I made the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `malloc`, you receive your `char*` to some memory. You own `size` bytes of that memory. But `malloc` does not prepare the memory you now own in any way. It is left in whatever state the previous owning process left it in. Thus, it could very likely be the case that the memory you receive already contains a string that is longer than `size`.

Thus when you begin your `strcat` and run to the end of the first string it will run past the length of `size`, and attempt to start writing to this memory. Here the problem arises, because you don't own the memory at that location, and thus the program segfaults.

On the other hand, if you initialise the strings by letting the first byte be `"\0"`, you are in effect setting the length of the string to 0 (because there are 0 bytes before the end token: `"\0"`). Thus when you begin your `strcat`, it will again run to the end of the first string, but this time the end is within `size`.

Beware you may still run into problems if the combined string would be longer than `size`.

Comment: "It is left in whatever state the previous owning process left it in." is only a possibility.  The state of memory is undefined.

Comment: indeed it is a single possibility, and you are right there are more possibilities, but they are listable, and if you dig in the code running on your machine (OS-code, code of other programs, code of your programs, code of libraries) you could work out exactly what the value would be. If you couldn't, the computer wouldn't have a chance of working it out either. Undefined is a rubbish term, because people use it wrongly. The state of memory may be unknown, or indeterministic from the viewpoint of the owning process, but memory cannot be undefined, every bit is either 0 or 1 and set thus.

Answer (score -1):

The statement

```
while(*s++);
```

make no sense for first two calls of `mystrcat` and invoke undefined behavior. You should not read an uninitialized memory.

You need to chech whether the first argument passed is an empty string or not

```
void mystrcat(char *s,char *t) {
    if(strlen(s))
    {
        while(*s++);
        s--;
    }
    while(*s++ = *t++);
}
```

Comment: `while(*s++);` is put there to find the end of first string.  This is one of the uses of `strcat` (find the end of first string, and then append the second).

Comment: @LuisColorado; Unfortunately it will not. For the first and second call `*s` will give an indeterminate value.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, he's looking for a replacement of standard `strcat(3)` function.  What use he makes afterwards is not specified.  Like using it on uninitialized variables like the ones result from `malloc(3)`.  Standard `strcat(3)` for sure crashes also. The wrong code is not _inside_ the function, but _outside_.

Comment: @LuisColorado; You are trying to say that `mystrcat( s1, "Hello " );` is valid in this code?
    `

Comment: Not.  But why doesn't he initialize the strings with `\0` ??? Why is he asking for a `strcat(3)` replacement, instead of a `strcpy(3)` replacement? The main difference between those two functions is just the initial search for the end of first string.  You cannot say the mistake is in the correctly written function, when it is in the main program.  Would the example work  replacing the written function with the standard one?

Comment: @LuisColorado; I really didn't get you. BTW, suggested a solution in my answer. *Would the example work replacing the written function with the standard one?*: No. It will fail in some cases.